# Как найти разность для коллекций состоящих из "пользовательских" данных?

Tags: c#, linq

Мне понадобилось найти *разность двух коллекций*, элементы коллекции это экземпляры пользовательского класса.

Для нахождения разности хочу воспользоваться linq методом [Except](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.0), описание метода говорит что для пользовательских типов надо сделать, одно из двух:

Отнаследовать пользовательский класс от `IEquatable<T>` и переопределить методы `Equals` & `GetHashCode` в исходном классе

```
public class OperationItem: IEquatable<OperationItem>
{

    public bool Equals(OperationItem other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.Name == other.Name && this.Code == other.Code;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as OperationItem);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (Name, Code).GetHashCode();
}
```

Или же создать нужный нам компаратор путем реализации интерфейса `IEqualityComparer<T>` и реализации уже знакомых нам методов `Equals` & `GetHashCode`

```
public class OperationItemComparer: IEqualityComparer<OperationItem>
{
    public bool Equals(OperationItem x, OperationItem y)
    {
        /*Реализация*/
    }

    public int GetHashCode(OperationItem obj)
    {
        /*Реализация*/
    }
}
```

Есть ли *существенная разница* в использовании того или иного способа, я предполагаю что второй способ используется в случае невозможности изменения исходного класса, но может есть другие причины использования того или иного способа?

Comment: Например, если в разных ситуациях равенство ваших объектов определяется по разному. Или, например, если вы не хотите пачкать ваши классы какой то логикой.

Comment: т.е. тот или иной способ определяется возможностью/желанием внесения изменений в исходный класс и необходимость реализации нескольких способов сравнения?

Comment: По сути да, так и есть

Comment: Вроде бы если не переопределять то по умолчанию будет использоваться сравнение ссылок.

Comment: _public override bool Equals(object obj)_ - не тот метод переопределяешь, в интерфейсе он конкретный тип принимает а не object

Comment: @Bald. важное отличие этих методов в том, что компарер как правило не имеет доступа к приватным полям, в то время как при реализации интерфейса такого ограничения нет

Comment: @Grundy, понял спасибо. но это вполне логичное поведение, в одном случае методы реализуются в самом классе(и по этому соответственно видна вся подноготная), во втором случае Мы видим только `public`

Comment: @Bald, да. это логично, но это все еще разница :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация типом интерфейса `IEquatable<>` добавляет отношение эквивалентности как естественное свойство самого типа. После этого *любые* коллекции и *любые* алгоритмы будут использовать это отношение по умолчанию!

Отсюда следуют некоторые ограничения: методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode` должны обязательно учитывать все свойства класса, во избежании сюрпризов в будущем. Кроме того, эти методы не могут учитывать каких-то посторонних данных, не связанных с проверяемым объектом.

В то же время, реализация `IEqualityComparer<>` добавляет некоторое отношение эквивалентности, которое можно как использовать, так и не использовать. Эта реализация может вообще быть приватной и использоваться всего в одном месте. Эта реализация может учитывать какие-то внешние настройки (так, `StringComparer` из стандартной библиотеки позволяет указать способ сравнения строк). Наконец, таких реализаций может быть много, и они не будут мешать друг другу.

Comment: *Отсюда следуют некоторые ограничения: методы Equals и GetHashCode должны обязательно учитывать все свойства класса, во избежании сюрпризов в будущем.* имеется ввиду что *реализация методов*, наверно не **все свойства**, а те на основании которых определятся уникальность экземпляра?

Comment: @Bald а что такое "свойство, не определяющее уникальность"?

Comment: в моем конкретном случае данный класс это класс описывающий таблицу в БД, и в этом случае для проверки мне достаточно только свойства `Id`, но в таблице есть и прочие свойства

Comment: @Bald предположим, у вас по какой-то причине есть два объекта с одним `Id`, но разными данными. Например, это две версии одной записи. Разве можно сказать, что эти два объекта - равны?

Comment: приведенный пример говорит о том что при сравнении объектов необходимо  учитывать **Id** & **Номер версии**? понятно что можно сверять все *поля*, я раньше думал что нет. я не прав?

Comment: @Bald а откуда у вас номер версии возьмётся? Учитывайте, что некоторая версия записи могла вообще никогда не храниться в базе...

Comment: например класс содержит следующие поля {Id, ParameterId, Value, AuthorId}, надо ли при определении уникальности объекта учитывать поле `AuthorId`, я считаю что автора изменений можно в этом случае не учитывать при сравнении объектов, я не прав?

Comment: @Bald вот я создал копию объекта, и изменил у копии автора. Равен ли новый объект старому?

Comment: @Bald лично я не понимаю как измененный объект может быть равен исходному.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92890/discussion-between-bald-and-pavel-mayorov).