# Как найти одинаковые элементы в массиве и удалить повторяющийся?

Tags: c#

Есть массив `PointCollection` с повторяющимися точками. Как удалить одну из них? Возможно ли это сделать через метод `Where`?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Linq и GroupBy

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сторону метода [Distinct](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск в коллекции List по нескольким значениям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100545/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-list-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: Как отсортировать массив на уникальность и записать результат в другой массив мне понятно. Я хотел бы не создавать дополнительные массивы для сортировки. Я бы хотел воспользоваться встроенным методом для массивов в c#. Наверняка такую функцию вшили в такие высокоуровневые массивы как `PointCollection`

Comment: Distinct() действительно описывает уникальность, но тем  не менее мне пока не удалось с помощью него отсортировать список.

Comment: для того что бы получить массив уникальных элементов необходимо к нему применить метод `Distinct`, предварительно необходимо реализовать методы `Equals` & `GetHashCode` для данного класса или же реализовать *компарор* `IEqualityComparer` для вашего класса, посмотрите мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975088/179270) может что почерпнете из него, иначе приведите больше конкретики что именно не получается, приведите сигнатуру класса, пример исходных данных

Comment: Так вам нужно удалить дублирующиеся элементы или отсортировать список?

Comment: Мне нужно удалить дублирующие элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_9.php):

```
var arr = new[] { <some values> };
var normArr = arr.Distinct(); // массив без дублирующихся значений
```

<sup>Примечание: *«Эта операция возвращает объект, перечисляющий элементы входной последовательности source и выдающий последовательность, в которой каждый элемент не эквивалентен предыдущим выданным. Эквивалентность элементов определяется методами GetHashCode и Equals»*.</sup>

---

"Тру-лоу-левел-импл" (такая же, как и в `Enumerable.Distinct`, только для массива):

```cs
[ThreadStatic]
static readonly HashSet<T> distinctCache = <...>;

public static void Distinct<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> source, Span<T> target)
{
    // checks skipped

    distinctCache.Clear();

    var copyIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        if (!distinctCache.Contains(source[i]))
            target[copyIndex++] = source[i];
}
```